# Store data in file system rather than SQL or Oracle database

Tags: c#, file-io

As I am working on Employee Management system, I have two table (for example) in database as given below.

**EmployeeMaster (DB table structure)**

EmployeeID (PK)   | EmployeeName | City

**MonthMaster (DB table structure)**

Month | Year | EmployeeID (FK) | PrenentDays | BasicSalary

Now my question is, I want to store data in file system rather than storing data in SQL or ORACLE.

I want my data in file system storage for Insert, Edit and Delete opration with keeping relation with objects too.

I am a C# developer, Could anybody have thoughts or idea on it. (To store data in file system with keeping relations between them)

Thanks in advance.

Any ideas on it?

Comment: You would have to create some datastructure that maps the data in order to keep the relationships. But if you are pulling the data from the db to begin with what possible advantage would you have by storing the data on the local machine? If you want to avoid the db traffic use a caching mechanism.

Comment: The obvious question is, why do you want to do this?  You're just going to end up reinventing (poorly) the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before diving into creating a database system, definitely you will need to know the inner workings of how relational databases really function. There are several ways to organize how you serialize your data whether in typical serialization as a dbo as a whole or the mysql solution of serializing the database file and tables in separate files for retrieval. Although doing the mysql way does reveal what tables are associated in the database object, the server does not have to load the whole dbo at once but according to what table(s) the statement(s) queries in the sql making the table cache smaller and faster. I tend to agree.

If you are not going to include some type of T-SQL language but simply by code, then you shouldn't have to many issues if you set up your classes right with a good cache (I mean you don't duplicate objects). If you are aiming for T-SQL support, then you will need to create a parser ,leaving me to say with experience in T-SQL parsing you got a lot of coding to do along with having to create token flags and checks and bounds.

Then you need to decide whether you want to incorporate views, functions and triggers.
If you are not ready for all that, then stick to a server database or an embedded database for your needs.

Comment: Rob, Thanks to your reply. Actually if you remember 10 year back, many business application (like Accounting, Banks) were developed in C OR C++ with file system storage. I am developing a small winform application with C# and .Net. Here, I want to use file system as a storage. Could you please let me know how would I do this by file IO in .Net? The product which is I am developing is NOT TOO BIG, but a small business application where user can work in multiple companies by creating company.[I can do this with simple MS Access DB by creating different MDB file per company!  but I dont want MDB]

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to perform EDIT/DELETE operations, then don't do this.  You will only end up recreating a database from scratch, so you might as well just use one. If you won't want to use SQLServer or Oracle, then use mysql, postgresql, or any of the various in-memory (persist-to-disk) databases out there. If you need to maintain human-readable, or plain/text based data-files, then still use an in-memory database, and save as .csv when persisting to disk.

Using external files can work well if you are doing batch processing, and focusing on APPEND operations only—I do this regularly, and achieve throughput that is simply impossible with a relational database.

You can also use the filesystem effectively if you use one file per record, and your operations are restricted to MAP/INSERT/DELETE/REPLACE; and, never attempt UPDATE. But again, if I need to do updates or correlations, or any of a number of other interesting queries I use a database.

Finally, you can use the filesystem if your operations are DUMP/RESTORE from in memory datastructures to a single file. In which case you should use whatever the standard XML persistence library is for your platform and just perform a RESTORE when you start the application, and a DUMP on exit or periodic save. Pretty much as soon as you move to multiple files you should be looking at a database and ORM again.

Ultimately, unless you are dealing with a very small amount of data; or you are dealing with a large amount of data (at least 100's of millions of records), stick with a database.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which is basically a "lightweight" DBMS hosted as a DLL in your process.
That would work well for you, if data format doesn't have to be human-readable and if concurrent data access (by several processes at once) is not required.